# Writing a dictionary to a file

Tags: dictionary, swift2, nsdictionary, plist

A dictionary of type [String:String] is read from a plist-file. Then I add a new key-value pair and - upon entry of background mode, I write it to the same path using the following code:

```
func saveToFile () {
    let mo_tmp: NSDictionary = ortdict as NSDictionary
    mo_tmp.writeToFile(fileat, atomically: true)
    print("mo_tmp:", mo_tmp)
    print("fileat:", fileat)
}
```

When relaunching the program, this same file is read in again. However, entries that I added to the dictionary (and shown in the above print-out) are nowhere. This happens when running the test on the Simulator or on a real iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of writeToFile() to see if it's true.  If it isn't, the dictionary failed to be written to the file because not all contained objects are property list objects.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: the result of writeToFile is indeed false, but for unknown reasons: The object mo1 is written out as:

Comment: mo1: {
    GPS = "47.2409, 8.7288, 423.0";
    "Jungfraujoch Switzerland" = "46.5481, 7.9839, 3580.0";
    "PMOD/WRC Davos" = "46.81350, 9.84455, 1587.21";
    "St\U00e4fa, Chapfwiesenstrasse 14" = "47.2409, 8.7288, 423.0";
    "St\U00e4fa, Chapfwiesenstrasse 25" = "47.2411, 8.7283, 422.9";
    "Summit Camp" = "72.58, -38.46, 3250.01";
    "ach was" = "47.2409, 8.7288, 423.0";
}

Comment: This is a dictionary - is'nt it?